# Trouble reading json-like input with python library types

Tags: python, json, decode

I have a some data read from a database (that I cannot change the structure of) where a single row might be something like

```
'[{
    "field1": "test", 
    "numericfield2": Decimal("1.8333333"),
    "datetimefield3": datetime.datetime(2023, 9, 21, 12, 00)
}]'
```

Obviously to make this intelligible in python I could do something like:

```
import json
json.loads('[{"field1": "test"}]')
```

however, when trying that on the whole payload I get a `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line [i] column [j] (char [j-1])` (where i and j refer to the position of the problematic fields.

The error is caused by the string data being of python (datetime and decimal) types when evaluated. Is there some way to get the json decoder to use something like:

```
import decimal
float(decimal.Decimal("1.8333333"))
# 1.83333

import datetime
datetime.datetime(2023, 9, 21, 12, 00).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
# '2023-09-21 12:00'
```

when attempting to read in the data? i.e. return all fields that are in Decimal 'type' to a float and all fields of datetime 'type' to a datetime. I know a little about using `object_hooks` with the `json.loads` method and it seems like the right approach but havent been able to quite get it work with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the JSON in the database might have been created with `json.dumps(data, default=repr)` or simply `repr(data)`

```py
import json
from decimal import Decimal
import datetime

data = [{
    "field1": "test", 
    "numericfield2": Decimal("1.8333333"),
    "datetimefield3": datetime.datetime(2023, 9, 21, 12, 00)
}]


serialized_data = repr(data)
serialized_data = json.dumps(data, default=repr)
```

To recover the original data you would need to use `eval()`

```py
import json
from decimal import Decimal
import datetime

data = [{
    "field1": "test", 
    "numericfield2": Decimal("1.8333333"),
    "datetimefield3": datetime.datetime(2023, 9, 21, 12, 00)
}]


serialized_data = repr(data)
parsed_data = eval(serialized_data)

assert parsed_data == data


serialized_data = json.dumps(data, default=repr)
parsed_data = eval(serialized_data)

assert parsed_data == data, "Doesn't work with Json dumped with repr"
```

Comment: yeah almost certainly the method of generation- for now I'm just extracting the fields manually using `str.extract` and then `eval` for those fields which need it but was wondering if theres some way to do it as the json is being loaded